# WooCommerce conditional custom checkout fields

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In WooCommerce, I'm currently trying to add a conditional custom field in the Checkout that shows a checkbox which if is checked displays an input field to insert an italian fiscal code (Codice Fiscale).

Thanks to various guides and plugin codes I was able to show it in the checkout but i'm doing something wrong with the code and having several issues:

1. By default i would like it to be NON required field, only if its checked it must become required.
2. If i try to proceed to cart inserting a valid or non codice fiscale i get this error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" where my theme usually shows checkout errors.
3. Display all this only in Italian Language (with WPML)
4. I can't know further errors while i can't solve the first two points.

**Note:** The Italian law requires that if a private customer asks for an invoice he must insert also his *(valid)* "codice fiscale" *(fiscal code)*.

To avoid complications, I didn't insert any advanced checking tools (that would require more fields, such as birthday). Instead I've set this short control via pattern tag:

```
jQuery('#cf_in').prop('pattern', "^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]$");
```

I've found it on internet but don't really know if it can work. I have alslo this one too:

```
function isCodiceFiscaleValid($valore,$codice_fiscale = true){
    $espressione = "^[a-z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-z][0-9]{2}[a-z][0-9]{3}[a-z]$";
    if(!$codice_fiscale){
        $espressione = "^[0-9]{11}$";
    }
    if ( eregi($espressione, $valore) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

After checking, once the inserted "Codice fiscale" *(fiscal code)* is good, we can proceed to checkout, displaying for customer and admin this "codice fiscale".

I would need additionally to print this on a PDF invoice using *WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips Pro* plugin *(commercial version)*.

References here (unfortunately can only post 2):

- [Link1 (custom plugin)](https://giorgiomen.it/woocommerce-codice-fiscale-e-partita-iva-nel-checkout/),
- [Link2 (JS check, note there's also php check in the same website)](http://www.icosaedro.it/cf-pi/vedi-codice.cgi?f=cf-js.txt)

Here the code *(added in my theme's `functions.php` file)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'cbi_cf_chkbox' );

function cbi_cf_chkbox ( $fields ) {
    if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='it' )
    $fields['billing']['checkbox_trigger'] = array(
    'type'      => 'checkbox',
    'label'     => __('Voui la fattura? (solo per privati)', 'cbi-custom-parts'),
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     ); 

    $fields['billing']['cf_in'] = array(
    'label'     => __('Inserisci il codice fiscale', 'cbi-custom-parts'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('RSSMRA85T10A562S', 'placeholder', 'cbi-custom-parts'),
    'class'     => array('display-none form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );
    return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'cbi_cf_conditionally_hide_show', 6);

function cbi_cf_conditionally_hide_show() {
   if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='it' )
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('input#checkbox_trigger').change(function(){           
            if (this.checked) {
                jQuery('#cf_in_field').fadeIn();
                jQuery('#cf_in_field').attr('required', true);
                jQuery('#cf_in').prop('pattern', "^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]$");
            } else {
                jQuery('#cf_in_field').fadeOut();
                jQuery('#cf_in_field input').val('');
                jQuery('#cf_in_field').attr('required', false);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
function isCodiceFiscaleValid($valore,$codice_fiscale = true){
    $espressione = "^[a-z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-z][0-9]{2}[a-z][0-9]{3}[a-z]$";
    if(!$codice_fiscale){
        $espressione = "^[0-9]{11}$";
    }
    if ( eregi($espressione, $valore) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/*
 * This method processes fields of checkout form
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'cbi_cf_process');
function cbi_cf_process() {
    if (! empty($_POST['cf_in']) ){
        $valid_codice_fiscale = isCodiceFiscaleValid($_POST['cf_in'],true);

        if( (!$valid_codice_fiscale) ){
            wc_add_notice( 'Wrong data in Codice Fiscale/Partita Iva field', 'error' );
        }
    }
}

/*
 * This method saves codice fiscale data in order meta and in user meta
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'cbi_cf_in_update_order_meta' );
function cbi_cf_in_update_order_meta ( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['cf_in'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'cf_in', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cf_in'] ) );
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        update_user_meta($order->user_id, 'cf_in', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cf_in'] ) );
    }
}

/*
 * This method shows the value of Partita Iva field after billing address
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'cbi_cf_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 10, 1 );
function cbi_cf_admin_order_data_after_billing_address($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Codice Fiscale', 'cbi-cf-invoice').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'cf_in', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

I will really appreciate if you could help me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this answer I can't treat PDF invoice, so you will get here:

- Solving the problem of conditional **"required"** field (point 1)
- Solving the problem of the [json](/questions/tagged/json) error (point 2)
- Displayed only for italian language (point 3)

Additionally I have:

- Revisited all your code and corrected many little errors.
- Added code to display and edit the backend user profile custom field value "codice fiscale": 
  [image]

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'cbi_cf_chkbox' );
function cbi_cf_chkbox ( $fields ) {
    if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE !='it' ) return $fields; // Only for Italy

    $fields['billing']['checkbox_cf'] = array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'label'     => __('Voui la fattura? (solo per privati)', 'cbi-custom-parts'),
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
     );

    $fields['billing']['cf_in'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Inserisci il codice fiscale', 'cbi-custom-parts'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('RSSMRA85T10A562S', 'placeholder', 'cbi-custom-parts'),
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
     );

    return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'cbi_cf_conditionally_hide_show', 6);
function cbi_cf_conditionally_hide_show() {
    if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE !='it' ) return; // Only for Italy
    $required = esc_attr__( 'required', 'woocommerce' );
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            var required = '<abbr class="required" title="<?php echo $required; ?>">*</abbr>'; // Required html

            $('#cf_in_field > #cf_in').prop('pattern', "^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]$"); // Doesn't seem to do something
            $('#cf_in_field').hide();

            $('input#checkbox_cf').change(function(){
                if (this.checked) {
                    $('#cf_in_field').fadeIn("fast", function(){
                        $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                        $('#cf_in_field > label').append(required);
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#cf_in_field').fadeOut("fast", function(){
                        $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                        $('#cf_in_field > label > .required').remove();
                    });
                }
                $('#cf_in_field').val('');
                $('#cf_in_field').removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#cf_in_field').removeClass("woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field");
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Utility function checking "codice fiscale" validity
function is_cf_valid( $valore, $codice_fiscale = true ){
    $espressione = "^[a-z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-z][0-9]{2}[a-z][0-9]{3}[a-z]$";
    if( ! $codice_fiscale ) $espressione = "^[0-9]{11}$";
    return eregi( $espressione, $valore ) ? true : false;
}

// Check custom fields value "codice fiscale" when submit and return error notices (if needed)
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'cbi_cf_process');
function cbi_cf_process() {
    if ( isset($_POST['checkbox_cf']) && $_POST['checkbox_cf'] == 1 ) {
        if( empty( $_POST['cf_in'] ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( "Please don't forget to enter your Codice Fiscale/Partita Iva", "cbi-custom-parts" ), "error" );
        } else {
            $valid_codice_fiscale = is_cf_valid( $_POST['cf_in'] );
            if( ( ! $valid_codice_fiscale ) )
                wc_add_notice( __( "Wrong data in Codice Fiscale/Partita Iva field", "cbi-custom-parts" ), "error" );
        }
    }
}

// Save the custom field value "codice fiscale" in order meta and in user meta
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'cbi_cf_in_update_order_meta' );
function cbi_cf_in_update_order_meta ( $order_id ) {
    if ( empty( $_POST['cf_in'] ) ) return;

    $customer_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', true );
    $user_codice_fiscale = get_user_meta( $order_id, 'codice_fiscale', true );

    if( ! empty( $user_codice_fiscale ) )
        update_user_meta($order->user_id, 'codice_fiscale', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cf_in'] ) );

    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_codice_fiscale', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cf_in'] ) );
}

// Backend : Display in Order edit pages, after billing address, the custom field value "codice fiscale"
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'cbi_cf_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 10, 1 );
function cbi_cf_admin_order_data_after_billing_address( $order ){
    $codice_fiscale = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_codice_fiscale', true );
    if( ! empty( $codice_fiscale ) )
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Codice Fiscale', 'cbi-cf-invoice').':</strong> ' . $codice_fiscale . '</p>';
}

// Backend: Display and edit user profile custom field value "codice fiscale" Only for Italy
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_extra_user_codice_fiscale', 1, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_extra_user_codice_fiscale', 1, 1 );
function add_extra_user_codice_fiscale( $user )
{

    //if( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'billing_country', true ) != 'IT' ) return;  // Only for Italy
    $codice_fiscale = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'codice_fiscale', true );
    if( empty( $codice_fiscale ) ) $codice_fiscale = '';
    ?>
        <h3><?php _e( "Codice fiscale", "cbi-custom-parts" ); ?></h3>
        <table class="form-table"><tr>
            <th><label for="codice_fiscale"><?php _e( "Codice fiscale", "cbi-custom-parts" ); ?></label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="codice_fiscale" value="<?php echo esc_attr($codice_fiscale); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
        </tr></table><br />
    <?php
}

// Backend: Save edited user profile custom field value "codice fiscale" Only for Italy
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_codice_fiscale' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_codice_fiscale' );
function save_extra_user_codice_fiscale( $user_id )
{
    if( ! empty( $_POST['codice_fiscale'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'codice_fiscale', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['codice_fiscale'] ) );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

All code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

Comment: Firstly: Thank you so much for helping me and using your time to helm me solve this problem. Your simply too kind and an angel. :) I've tried your revised code and works as i've wanted but still, whatever codice fiscale i put, or if i fill it with some chars, gives me error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0". I think it's related to is_cf_valid and function cbi_cf_process. I found another php code that could check it: http://www.icosaedro.it/cf-pi/vedi-codice.cgi?f=cf-php.txt can this work? You've done already alot, so i'll understand if you can't answer this. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi there!  Thanks again for your help, i've managed to make it work removing the check that eventually wasn't needed.  Now i'm trying to display the field also on thank you page but that field remains white. This is my latest result: https://pastebin.com/fHHKrdXD  Hope you'll have time to check it :)  Knowing this i will know also how to add the field to emails :) Many thanks again

Comment: Hey man, sorry still new to S.O. , now I did accept your answer. Ok, about ACF later i will add some more info. Thank you very much for the inputs and help! :)