# Add a checkbox below a specific shipping method in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I'm trying to customize the **WC checkout page**. In my checkout page I've set **2 shipping methods**. **My goal is to add a custom field down below the  first shipping method**. To achieve this I used the hook I mentioned below.

```
woocommerce_after_shipping_rate
```

But my problem with this is, it just adds the same field for each shipping methods available. How can I manage to add an input field **for a particular shipping method**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `$method` argument that is an instance of the [`WC_Shipping_Rate`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Rate.html) Object you can target any shipping method Id using `get_id()` method, like in this example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'checkout_shipping_additional_field', 20, 2 );
function checkout_shipping_additional_field( $method, $index )
{
    if( $method->get_id() == 'flat_rate:12' ){
        echo '<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="shipping_custom_1" id="shipping_custom_1" value="1" class="shipping_method shipping_custom_1">
        <label for="shipping_custom_1">Custom label</label>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

[image]

---

Similar answers:

- [Shipping carrier custom fields validation in Woocommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159445/shipping-carrier-custom-fields-validation-in-woocommerce-checkout-page/49163797#49163797)
- [Dynamic shipping fee based on custom radio buttons in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558286/dynamic-shipping-fee-based-on-custom-radio-buttons-in-woocommerce/51572051#51572051)
- [Update fee dynamically based on radio buttons in Woocommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457961/update-fee-dynamically-based-on-radio-buttons-in-woocommerce-checkout/49470265#49470265)

Comment: The issue with this is as soon as you select an option, the content disappears. Is there a way around this?