# WooCommerce shipping input type radio editing issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm struggling with Woocommerce shipping input type radio editing. I don't know any programing language so I want to ask you if you can guide me little.

I would like to add shipping method "Zasielkovna".
It should work like this

[click on radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWPhF.png)

[window appears and you choose pickup point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNz6T.jpg)

[under this shipping option is written chosen pick up point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9qty.png)

Guide from zasielkovna company says that I have to add this before end of /body tag which I did.

```
<script>
    var packetaSelectorOpen = '.packeta-selector-open';
    var packetaSelectorBranchName = '.packeta-selector-branch-name';
    var packetaSelectorBranchId = '.packeta-selector-branch-id';
    

    var packetaPrimaryButtonColor = '#39b54a';
    var packetaBackgroundColor = '#ffffff';
    var packetaFontColor = '#555555';
    var packetaFontFamily = 'Arial';
</script>
<script src="https://widget.packeta.com/www/js/packetaWidget.js" data-api-key=""></script>
```

Then you have to add these 3 selectors

1. **.packeta-selector-open**
   Typically button (input[type=”radio”]), after click, system opens.
2. **.packeta-selector-branch-name**
   place of the name of pickup point,
   (shipping Zásilkovna, pickup point XXX)
3. **.packeta-selector-branch-id**
   ID of pickup point, which is used to export data do Zasielkovna. Typically input[type=hidden], which is saved to order.

How can I add these selectors to my woocommerce cart shipping option 'Zásilkovna' ?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D8mG.png)

My store https://www.cukrovavata.cz/

Sorry for my English

Comment: Note that *"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**."* As this is related to a third party shipping plugin and you should continue asking their support. The provided information and code doesn't allow to help you, as we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. Company doesnt provide plugin for this. These is only paid third party plugin. I wonder if there can be done code similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62191919/add-radio-buttons-to-specific-shipping-method-on-woocommerce-checkout

Comment: That is what I mean: A third party plugin (paid or not). AS StackOverFlow is not a free coding service, We expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt, with all details and explanations, that allows us reproduce any issue that you have, when asking for help.