# Make only one of the billing fields required (Email or Phone) in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to give the customer a choice? So the customers can decide how we can contact them.

Email or phone. Both are required but it is enough to fill any of them. They do not need to fill these 2 fields.

@Martin Mirchev suggests a select menu.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 
'wc_custom_email_phone_field_checkout' );
function wc_custom_email_phone_field_checkout( $fields ) {
$fields['billing']['billing_contact'] = array(
'label'       => __('How we contact you?', 'woocommerce'),
'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
'required'    => false,
'clear'       => false,
'type'        => 'select',
'options'     => array(
    'email' => __('Email', 'woocommerce' ),
    'phone' => __('Phone', 'woocommerce' )
    )
);
return $fields;
}
```

This code adds a select menu. Then how can I do an if-else?

Comment: You have to create some selection and depending on what they pref either mail or phone and make it required. There are many examples how to add extra fields and modify the default ones. Keep in mind email is required anyway for the registration.

Comment: Yes, the dropdown menu like "how we contact you" and then the customer can select. But then I need to do an if-else. I could not figure it out yet.

Comment: Here is one example with conditions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299376/woocommerce-conditional-custom-checkout-fields

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.

I keep the email field and created a select

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'wc_custom_email_phone_field_checkout' );
function wc_custom_email_phone_field_checkout( $fields ) {
$fields['billing']['billing_contact'] = array(
     'label'       => __('How should we contact you?', 'woocommerce'),
     'placeholder' => __('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
     'required'    => false,
     'clear'       => false,
     'type'        => 'select',
     'options'     => array(
         'email' => __('Email', 'woocommerce' ),
         'phone' => __('WhatsApp', 'woocommerce' )
         )
     );
return $fields;
}
```

[image]

I also created an input

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_whatsapp_fields');
function custom_woocommerce_whatsapp_fields( $fields ){
$fields['billing']['billing_whatsapp'] = array(
    'label'       => __('Enter your WhatsApp number', 'woocommerce'), 
    'placeholder' => __('Enter your WhatsApp number', 'woocommerce'), 
    'required'    => false, // if field is required or not
    'clear'       => false, // add clear or not
    'type'        => 'text', // add field type
    'class'       => array('whatsapp'),   // add class name
    'priority'    => 25, // Priority sorting option
);
return $fields;
}
```

The input field is invisible with css.

```
 .form-row.whatsapp {
     display: none;
  }
```

If the option phone is selected, it becomes visible.

[image]

```
let selectEl = document.getElementById('billing_contact');
selectEl.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
if (e.target.value == 'phone') {
document.getElementById('billing_whatsapp_field').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('billing_whatsapp_field').classList.add('validate-required');
 } else {
document.getElementById('billing_whatsapp_field').style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById('billing_whatsapp_field').classList.remove('validate-required');
 }
 });
```

And finally, if the phone option is selected and form sent with the phone field empty:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'whatsapp_checkout_fields', 9999 );
function whatsapp_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if (($_POST['billing_contact']  == 'phone')) {          
        $fields['billing']['billing_whatsapp']['required'] = true;
        } else {
        $fields['billing']['billing_whatsapp']['required'] = false;  
    }
return $fields;
}
```

[image]

If the mail option is selected, the WhatsApp field is not required.

In both cases, I wanted to keep the email as a required field for several reasons. But you can make it false when the phone is selected.